# Filter Replace string that contains given pattern

Tags: r

I am currently normalizing categorical variable in my dataset.

I have to normalize transmission of cars to either Manual or Automatic.

My initial data looks like this (Note that this is make up data)

```
Make    | Transmission |  Price
BWM     6 Speed Automatic  50000
TOYOTA  5 Speed Automatic  40000
BWM     7 Speed Manual     70000
NISSAN  3 Speed Automatic  50000
TOYOTA  5 Speed Manual     30000
```

My goal is to convert any transmission that contains Automatic to "Automatic" and transmission that contains Manual to "Manual"

My current approach is to use gsub()

```
df$Transmission <- gsub("6 Speed Automatic", "Automatic", df$Transmission)
df$Transmission <- gsub("5 Speed Automatic", "Automatic", df$Transmission)
df$Transmission <- gsub("3 Speed Automatic", "Automatic", df$Transmission)
df$Transmission <- gsub("7 Speed Manual", "Manual", df$Transmission)
df$Transmission <- gsub("5 Speed Manual", "Manual", df$Transmission)
```

In the real daaset, there are many different type of Automatic and Manual Transmission. I don't think copy pasting gsub() function is efficient.

I am trying to find a way to replace using regex, however the best i can do is identify them using dplyr filter

```
filter(df, grepl("Automatic", Transmission))
```

Is there anyway I can replace string that contains Automatic to "Automatic" and string that contain Manual as "Manual". Using Multiple gsub is not efficient at all in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. The spelling for "Automatic" & "Manual" are *exactly* so in all possible Transmission values (i.e. no typos, no change in upper / lower case, etc.); and
2. There's no Transmission value that includes both "Automatic" & "Manual".

Something like the following should work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Transmission2 = case_when(
    grepl("Automatic", Transmission) ~ "Automatic",
    grepl("Manual", Transmission) ~ "Manual",
    TRUE ~ ""))
```

Data:

```
df <- read.csv(
  text = "Make, Transmission, Price
  BWM,     6 Speed Automatic,  50000
  TOYOTA,  5 Speed Automatic,  40000
  BWM,     7 Speed Manual,     70000
  NISSAN,  3 Speed Automatic,  50000
  TOYOTA,  5 Speed Manual,     30000"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fast data.table way.

```
library(data.table)

Make <- c('BWM','TOYOTA','BWM','NISSAN','TOYOTA') 
Transmission <- c('Speed Automatic','Speed Automatic','Speed Manual','Speed Automatic','Speed Manual')


DT <- data.table(Make = Make, Transmission = Transmission)

DT[, Transmission_new := ifelse(Transmission == 'Speed Automatic', 
    'Automatic', 'Manual')]

> DT
     Make    Transmission Transmission_new
1:    BWM Speed Automatic        Automatic
2: TOYOTA Speed Automatic        Automatic
3:    BWM    Speed Manual           Manual
4: NISSAN Speed Automatic        Automatic
5: TOYOTA    Speed Manual           Manual
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
> df <- data.table(Transmission = c('6 Speed Automatic',
                                  '5 Speed Automatic',
                                  '7 Speed Manual',
                                  '3 Speed Automatic',
                                  '5 Speed Manual'))

> df[, Transmission := str_extract(string = Transmission, pattern = 'Automatic|Manual')]
> df

   Transmission
1:    Automatic
2:    Automatic
3:       Manual
4:    Automatic
5:       Manual
```